# Table are not populated after insert sql

Tags: mysql, sql

In the Java programming language, I have two entities one to one. I'm trying to create a database with those two tables. In the `employee` table I have a column of `employee_detail_id`. The problem is that this column does not fill in automatically, it is not assigned an ID when I create a user in the employee table.

This is how I tried:

```
    use `etsystem`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee_detail`;

CREATE TABLE `employee_detail` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `work_experience` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hobby` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  language varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee`;

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_detail_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_DETAIL_idx` (`employee_detail_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DETAIL` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_detail_id`) REFERENCES `employee_detail` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Foreign keys aren't filled in automatically. After you create the `employee_detail` row, use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID that was assigned, and store that in `employee_detail_id`.

Comment: Example: `INSERT INTO employee_detail (hobby, work_experience) VALUES ('none', 123);` ... `INSERT INTO employee (first_name, last_name, employee_detail_id) VALUES ('first', 'last', last_insert_id());`  Make sure these are executed in the same session, in order, and with no intervening `INSERT`(s) which impact `last_insert_id()`.